# Convert a Single line of JSON to csv using jq in shell bash script

Tags: json, bash, shell, csv, jq

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "age": "22",
  "state": "Texas",
  "city": "Dallas",
  "dailysteps": 99,
  "weeklysteps": 2377,
  "monthlysteps": 330003
}
```

For example, i have this line of json data (lets call it data.json) and i need to convert it to csv with the following output format (pls, output example in picture attached).I'm only interested in picking out the dailysteps, weeklysteps and monthlysteps and adding a "Total Steps" column like in the picture attached

It should have its custom Title Headers like this

```
Daily Steps, Weekly Steps, Monthly Steps, Total Steps
99 , 2377 , 330003 , 332479
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9BQ4.png)

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this do it?

```bash
jq -r '
  ["Daily Steps", "Weekly Steps", "Monthly Steps", "Total Steps"], 
  ([.dailysteps, .weeklysteps, .monthlysteps] | . + [add])
  | @csv
' data.json
```

```json
"Daily Steps","Weekly Steps","Monthly Steps","Total Steps"
99,2377,330003,332479
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KPymw_laEkw)

---

To add another column with the current hour in the local timezone (as requested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73102270/convert-a-single-line-of-json-to-csv-using-jq-in-shell-bash-script/73102299#comment129110684_73102299)), using `now - 3600 | localtime[3]` would be an option:

```bash
jq -r '
  ["Hours", "Daily Steps", "Weekly Steps", "Monthly Steps", "Total Steps"],
  ([.dailysteps, .weeklysteps, .monthlysteps] | [now - 3600 | localtime[3]] + . + [add])
  | @csv
'
```

```json
"Hours","Daily Steps","Weekly Steps","Monthly Steps","Total Steps"
22,99,2377,330003,332479
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yJhWh9t9KWU)

To add the hour from a parameter provided externally to `jq`, use the `--argjson` option:

```bash
jq -r --argjson H "$(date +%H -d "1 hour ago")" '
  ["Hours", "Daily Steps", "Weekly Steps", "Monthly Steps", "Total Steps"],
  ([.dailysteps, .weeklysteps, .monthlysteps] | [$H] + . + [add])
  | @csv
'
```

```json
"Hours","Daily Steps","Weekly Steps","Monthly Steps","Total Steps"
22,99,2377,330003,332479
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. 

i have a quick question. where do i add the 'date +%H' (this shows the curent hour) if i was to add it to the code @pmf

Comment: @igbins09 There's no `date` in your question (thus I don't know where it should come from and where you want to have it added) but `now | localtime[3]` will give you the hours in your timezone.

Comment: i apologize for being vague. i should have added to the question.

so i want to add one more column called "Hours" at the front of the table right before "Daily Steps". so basically the "Hours" column will always generated by the current timezone

In bash script,     date +%H -d "1 hour ago"  will generate the current hour minus 1 hour., that's what i wanted to add to the code as maybe a variable  @pmf

Comment: @igbins09 I have added a local hours column to my response (one using `now - 3600 | localtime[3]`, the other one an external value using `date +%H -d "1 hour ago"`).

Comment: wow, it worked. though i tried the external parameter. you're the best @pmf